# Copy Data From ODBC Connection To Local Database

Tags: sql-server, caching, connection, copy, odbc

I would like to create a cached copy of the tables from a ODBC connected database on our MS SQL server. We are currently connecting to the ODBC connection directly from a few excel sheets and running the query's. They take about 1 - 2 minutes to complete and when being run several times a day that can add up quick. So to try and solve this I copied a couple tables from the ODBC connection and ran a query and it took about 11 seconds. I would like to create a copy of the tables and update them every hour or so. But I only want to update the tables and rows that changed to try and keep server load down. I would like to do this as a stored procedure. I am not very good with SQL and was wondering if there was a semi simple way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure that runs your query and just modify it slightly to output to a physical table.

For example:

```
select a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.City, b.State, b.zip into _temp_report
from customers a join addresses b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

In the example above, the **into _temp_report** part is the important part. It will create a new physical table with the results of your query.

Then you can simply point the reports to that table.

You can use SQL Server Agent to create a job that runs the stored procedure on a schedule.

You'll obviously need to add some logic to remove the _temp_report table on each run of the stored procedure so you don't try to re-create it each time the job runs.

Comment: That just copies over the tables right? it does not add the rows that changed? The database that I am caching is about 200mb in size and it takes about 20 min to run the full caching query. I want to select just the rows from the tables that have been added. I know how I would do this in C# or VB but I don't want to create another service for the server. I would rather it be a stored procedure that I can run periodically

Comment: The fake query I wrote would be in a stored procedure. It doesn't just copy tables over. It runs your query that takes 20 minutes (by the way 20 minutes for 200mb is very surprising. I bet adding indexes and some other little tweaks would take that time _way_ down) and outputs it to a temporary table. You can modify the query to only consider rows that have been recently updated/added. The big idea/main point is that you can run a sproc that creates a new table bsaed only on the query from the sproc.

Comment: That makes a little more sense. Unfortunately I cannot add indexes to the database because it is a read only database from our accounting software(Peachtree/Sage 50)